# Unity Android Intents

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to launch an android app using Intents in Unity. Using the code I've written, I'm able to open the app, but I'm trying to make it launch into a specific action inside that app.

I found a link on a website that does what I want, but its not in the right format
which is:
`intent://placeID=370731277#Intent;scheme=robloxmobile;package=com.roblox.client;S.browser_fallback_url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.roblox.client;end`

When I click on this link on the website, it launches the app to the state I want (Specifically, it launches the game with the id 370731277)

I had a look inside the AndroidManifest.xml and found this :

```
<activity android:name="com.roblox.client.ActivityProtocolLaunch" android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="robloxmobile" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Which seems to be the activity which the link is running.

My Unity code (C#) is as follows

```
string data = "robloxmobile://placeID=370731277";
string package = "com.roblox.client";


AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
AndroidJavaObject packageManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

AndroidJavaObject launchIntent = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", package);
AndroidJavaObject uriData = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", data);

launchIntent = launchIntent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setData", uriData);

currentActivity.Call("startActivity", launchIntent);
```

This succesfully opens the app, however the game (id 370731277)

I feel like I have everything I need here, I'm just not understanding something - any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Ended up fixing it - essentially through trial and error, I found I have to be really specific about the activity I want to run. I have to tell it the activity, the action and the scheme + data. This is my new working code.

```
    string url = "robloxmobile://placeID=370731277";


    AndroidJavaClass unityPlayer = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
    AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unityPlayer.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
    AndroidJavaObject packageManager = currentActivity.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");

    AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
    AndroidJavaObject uriData = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("parse", url);

    AndroidJavaObject i = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", "com.roblox.client");

    i.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setClassName", "com.roblox.client", "com.roblox.client.ActivityProtocolLaunch");
    i.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", "android.intent.action.VIEW");
    i.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setData", uriData);

    currentActivity.Call("startActivity", i);
```