# Send data from unity app to android app on button press

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have two apps one is android java app and other is unity app

Unity app recognize the object and shows some details. What i want to do is if user clicks the button which is shown when the object is identified, i want to send that information to the java android app so that the app can use that data to perform certain functions. How can i send the data and switch from unity to java android app after user clicks the button?

EDIT: For any one looking for the answer. I manage to do it by the code below

### IN UNITY APP:

```
    public void LaunchAppMessage()
    {
        string bundleId = "com.example.sidenavtest";
        bool fail = false;
        string message = "message";
        AndroidJavaClass up = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
        AndroidJavaObject ca = up.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
        AndroidJavaObject packageManager = ca.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getPackageManager");
        AndroidJavaObject launchIntent = null;

        try
        {
            launchIntent = packageManager.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("getLaunchIntentForPackage", bundleId);
            launchIntent.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", "arguments", message);
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            fail = true;
        }

        if (fail)
        {
            Application.OpenURL("https://google.com");
        }
        else
        {
            ca.Call("startActivity", launchIntent);
        }
        up.Dispose();
        ca.Dispose();
        packageManager.Dispose();
        launchIntent.Dispose();
    }
```

### IN ANDROID APP

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String userName;

        if (extras != null) {
            userName = extras.getString("arguments");

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to have both applications on the same device.
Simplest way would be to save the data ino a file in the unity application and read from that file in the android application. But i think you can even attach data on application calls so that you dont even need to save it temporarily.
Opening the Android app from Unity is possible aswell. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51460822/unity-android-intents) someone asked the same question and got some working answer.

Edit: From what i can gather you can transfer your data via intents, it seem's like most people work with [JAR-Plugin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidJARPlugins.html) from where you can make a intent call.

Comment: I have managed to open other app from unity app using the code in the post(i have updated the post with the code). Is there any way i can also sent some data to the java android app by using that code.

Comment: i think [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1444040/how-to-send-multiple-screenshots-to-the-android-in.html) could do what you want.